# How can I source a variable from a shell script and also pipe the output of the script?

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, export, variable-assignment

I have a script `test.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
export VAR1=abc123
echo $VAR1
```

I want the variable set in `test.sh` to be set in the shell from which I run this script, so I use `source`:

```
$ source test.sh                    
abc123
$ echo $VAR1    
abc123
```

But let's say I want to do something with the output of `test.sh`. It seems that if I pipe the output of `test.sh`, sourcing the variable no longer works:

```
$ VAR1=xyz
$ source test.sh | sed 's/abc/xyz/g'
xyz123
$ echo $VAR1                        
xyz
```

As opposed to the expected:

```
$ VAR1=xyz
$ source test.sh | sed 's/abc/xyz/g'
xyz123
$ echo $VAR1    
abc123
```

How can I get around this if I want to set a variable and modify the output using one script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run :

```
source test.sh | sed 's/abc/xyz/g'
```

`source test.sh` is run in a subshell so has no effect on the parent shell.

You need process substitution :

```
source test.sh > >(sed 's/abc/xyz/g')
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. But why does `source test.sh` only run in a subshell when its output is being piped?

Comment: @Stonecraft see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024.